# When I add this line JS code breaks. Apple Mainstage Scripter Plugin

Tags: javascript

Can anyone spot the error in this Javascript?
(It's for the Apple Mainstage scripter plugin).
I'm trying to transpose notes down an octave that fall below a certain "fold point" note.

When I add the "event.pitch -= 12;" line the next else statement is not allowed.  I'm wondering if this needs to be wrapped in a function somehow.  I'm new to coding and have mostly used lua but the scripting plugin in Mainstage uses Javascript.
Many thanks for your time.

```
 // transpose notes below fold point


  var activeNotes = [];


function HandleMIDI(event)

{

if (event instanceof NoteOn) {

    if (event.pitch < GetParameter('Fold Point'))

    event.pitch -= 12; //        when I add this line the 'else' two lines below is not allowed

        event.send();

    else {

        activeNotes.push(event);

        event.send()

    }

}

else if (event instanceof NoteOff) {

    for (i=0; i < activeNotes.length; i++) {

        if (event.pitch == activeNotes[i].pitch) {

            event.send();

            activeNotes.splice(i,1);

            break;

        }

    }

}

else { // pass non-note events through

    event.send();

}

  }


  var PluginParameters = [


{   name:'Fold Point', type:'lin',

    minValue:0, maxValue:127, numberOfSteps:127, defaultValue:30}

  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add curly braces when the `if` statement covers more than one line. Like this:

```
if (event instanceof NoteOn) {
  if (event.pitch < GetParameter('Fold Point')) {
    event.pitch -= 12; //        when I add this line the 'else' two lines below is not allowed
    event.send();
  } else {
    activeNotes.push(event);
    event.send()
  }
}
```

Notice that I put a curly brace after the second "if" and before the "else".

Comment: Ok I'll give that a try when I get back to my machine.  Do you know why it is that the extra curly brackets aren't necessary when if IF structure is as in my original post and just the event. pitch line is not present?

Comment: It's the way JavaScript is designed. An `if` makes the following **statement** or **block** conditional. Code blocks are made by enclosing more than one statement (line) in curly braces. Without curly braces, the `if` only affects the line of code immediately following. With curly braces, it affects everything in the block.